# Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs

```
private processFormSubmission = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): Promise<void> => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        axios.patch(`https://609e417f33eed800179581a7.mockapi.io/api/customers/data/${this.state.id}`, this.state.values).then(data => {
            this.setState({ submitSuccess: true, loading: false })
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.history.push('/');
            }, 1500)
        })
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKFrM.png)

i create CRUD app, and when i use the edit function, i get error like that. pls help me.

Comment: You have to enable CORS in the backend. If you are using an external API, then you have make a small proxy app which fetches the data from the api and sends to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

We can do two things:

1. We can ask the Middletier/API team to allow your UI's FQDN inside their Allow -CORS list.
2. In my local I have added `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"` inside the `package.json`.

[image]

[image]